# how to receive arrayList<dto> in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, struts

here is my code  where i am send a list of GroupDTOI type as a list in session so how can i receive it in jsp and iterate it.

```
ArrayList<GroupDTO> groupList = new ArrayList<GroupDTO>();
    groupList = new GroupList().setList(); 

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("groupList", groupList);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do it through JSTL as shown [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0380__JSTL/UseForEachtoLoopThroughArrayList.htm) or through the use of the `<%` `%>` tags as shown [here](http://www.jguru.com/forums/view.jsp?EID=1268302).

Answer (score 2):

Use JSTL.

```
<c:forEach var="group" items="${groupList}">
    This is my Group - ${group}
</c:forEach>
```

The more ugly way <strike>is</strike> was to use scriptlets.

```
<%
    ArrayList<GroupDTO> groupList = (ArrayList<GroupDTO>) session.getAttribute("groupList");

    for(int i = 0; i < groupList.size(); i++) {
%>
    My Group is <%=groupList.get(i)%>
<%
    }
%>
```